# Is it secure to do subfield vector oblivious linear evaluation (VOLE) over a Ring $\mathbb{Z}_{2^k}$?

Tags: pseudo-random-function, oblivious-transfer, pseudo-random-correlation

In the paper "Efficient Pseudorandom Correlation Generators: Silent OT Extension and More (https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-26954-8)" Boyle et. al. proposed subfield vole.

For standard vector oblivious
linear evaluation correlation one has, $\vec{v}+\vec{w}=\vec{u}*x$ ($v_i, w_i, u_i, x \in \mathbb{F}_p$).

And for subfield VOLE correlation, $x \in \mathbb{F}_q$ ($q = p^r$), $v_i, w_i \in \mathbb{F}_q$, $u_i \in \mathbb{F}_p$.
Boyle et. al. mentioned that $\vec{u} * x$ can be seen as the tensor product (vector outer product).

My question is when considering VOLE over $\mathbb{Z}_{2^k}$, is it secure to do such subfield VOLE while interpreting $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{2^k}^{r}$ as a vector of $\mathbb{Z}_{2^k}$?

Thanks for any suggestions and helps.

Comment: One of the authors, Geoffroy Couteau regularly posts here. Can you expand the acronym (VOLE) in the question?

Comment: The short answer is "yes but some care is in order", I'll expand when I get some time.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you are referring to the comment on page 9 of [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/448.pdf). Indeed, given a pseudorandom $x\in \mathbb{F}_{p^r}$, you can parse it as a pseudorandom $\vec x \in \mathbb{F}_{p}^r$, and re-interpret the additive shares of $x\cdot \vec u \in \mathbb{F}_p^n$ as shares of $\vec x \otimes \vec u \in \mathbb{F}_p^{n\cdot t}$.

Now, if you do a VOLE over $\mathbb{Z}_{2^k}$, you can perfectly use $\vec x\in \mathbb{Z}_{2^k}^r$ to get shares of $\vec x \otimes \vec u$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{2^k}^{r \cdot n}$. This does not even use subfield VOLE (which, here, would actually be subring VOLE, since we're not working over a field). Indeed, this is simply doing $r$ parallel VOLEs with receiver inputs $x_1, \cdots, x_r$, fixing a sender vector $\vec u$. Our construction easily allows fixing the vector $\vec u$ across multiple instances, so nothing goes wrong here.

Regarding security, however, a word of caution: the space where you generate the VOLEs is tied to the underlying assumption. When generating VOLE over $\mathbb{Z}_{2^k}$, you end up with a construction that is secure under a variant of the LPN / syndrome decoding problem over the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{2^k}$. This has been used in several works (e.g. [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/750) and [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/819.pdf)). For a recent study of this assumption, see [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/712). In particular, this work points out that there is an easy "reduce modulo 2" attack on LPN over this ring that reduces the instance to an LPN instance over $\mathbb{F}_2$ and halves the amount of noise (since a random noise over $\mathbb{Z}_{2^k}$ is sent to 0 modulo 2 with probability half). This has to be taken into account when choosing parameters.